# Product page Error 404 - Magento2.4.5

Tags: url-rewrite

We have a configurable product. When we go to this product we got error 404. When we go to product by typing url, same error. When I go to Url rewrites, and change this product url to redirect type 301(permanent), then its working. But now the url is like "catalog/product/view/id/35751/s/public-speaking" not the actual product url. Why its not working with the actual url. Please help.